# Why does variable store different value than what user inputs?

Tags: c, data-storage

I am having a problem setting a variable entered by the user. I entered something in and it stores another value. Pretty frustrating. So any guidance would be great.

Be advised, there are quite a few `printf()`, as I was trying to pinpoint the problem. Also I am still trying to get a hold of C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int vehicletype, in, out; // User Entered Info
int vehicleID[5000];
float vehicleCharge[5000]; 
int i; 

// Variables for Main Function
int q; // Loop Control
float z;

int main (){

    for(q = 1; q != 1518944; q++) {
        printf("Enter your position in the parking queue: ");
        // Take the queue entered by the user and assign it to i 
        scanf("%d\n", &i);

        // Take the user input(which is being held in the variable i) and place it into the 'i'
        //position of the ID array
        vehicleID[q] = i;

        printf("Enter the time(past 0600) you wish to start parking: \n");
        //take the time and pass it to the time function to determine roundup
        scanf("%d\n", &in);
        printf("Enter the time(before 2200) you wish to leave: \n");
        scanf("%d\n", &out);
        printf("Time in: %d\nTime out: %d\n", in, out);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

@M.M I should be able to enter 0617 into the "in"  variable and 1547 for the "out" (I use this later to find out how much they parked) but the output I get when checking the variables by printing "in" and "out" is 1 and 399 respectively.

Comment: What does your compiler say when you try to compile this code?

Comment: For some specific input, what is the actual and expected output? What variable seem to change value? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? And please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: for (z = 1; z == 5000; z++)    <-- z== 5000? really?

Comment: You must ALWAYS check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, but more urgently please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It would be helpful if you posted compilable code; you've omitted headers and not defined `vehicleID` or `vehicleCharge`  (or `z`, `q`, `timespent` and probably other variables too) so we can't begin to guess what you've done with those.  The first `for` loop is wrong as @Ccr pointed out; your second loop `for(q = 1; q != 1518944; q++) {
` is also eccentric; who is going to type in 1.5 million entries, and how big are your arrays.

Comment: @Ccr thats not the problem, it has a purpose elsewhere

Comment: @EOF It actually compiles without any warning or errors(still need to debug some functions but those functions are useless if the incorrect value is being passed on to them)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler They are defined, i thought that me excluding them was being minimal. Ill check your out the link thx. The input is the car number and then you input the entrance time and exit time.

Comment: @El_Nino: You would be more minimal by eliminating parts of the code not necessary for reproducing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: `for(q = 1; q != 1518944; q++) {`... I can see the frustration... Provided everything else is defined correctly and that you're just not showing us, you're asking users to enter the same information at least 1,518,943 times before the program properly exits.

Comment: Omitting the variable definitions makes the code (sub)minimal but violates the complete and verifiable parts of an MCVE.

Comment: `1518944` - Looks like a committee is involved somewhere!

Comment: Most of the global variables should be local; the possible exceptions would be the arrays. This won't directly affect the behaviour now, but makes the code harder to maintain in the long run. Granted, homework problems seldom have a long run, but that's not an excuse for sloppy coding.

Comment: Mobile apps do not make good programming tools — the spell checkers are a nuisance when programming.  —— Also, don't use a newline at the end of a scanf format string. It means "read up to the next character that is not a blank, tab or newline". That means the user has to predict what the program will ask for next. Newlines at the end of printing operations are good; in scanning, they are diabolical.

Comment: In the question you should include the exact input you supplied, and the output you got for that input.  (Also explain how the output differs from what you expected, if it's not obvious)

Comment: `"%d\n"` should be `"%d"` in scanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some more or less working code.  I don't understand the 1518944 limit, but the code takes steps to ensure that regardless of how many entries you make, the code won't write out of bounds of the array `vehicleID`.  It also checks some numbers for validity, and echoes its inputs.  The leading newlines on some of the outputs makes the output appear semi-sane when the data is written via another program (a random number generator was what I used to generate numbers 1-5000 and two times 0600-2200).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int vehicleID[5000];

int main(void)
{
    for (int q = 1; q != 1518944; q++)
    {
        int in, out;
        int i;
        printf("\nEnter your position in the parking queue: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1)
            break;

        vehicleID[q % 5000] = i;

        printf("Enter the time (past 0600) you wish to start parking: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &in) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Enter the time (before 2200) you wish to leave: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &out) != 1)
            break;
        if (in < 600 || in > 2200 || out < 600 || out > 2200 || in >= out)
            printf("Invalid times (in %.4d, out %.4d)\n", in, out);
        else
            printf("\nPosition: %d; Time in: %.4d; Time out: %.4d\n", i, in, out);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Note that inputs are checked, and echoed.  Checking is a crucial programming technique; printing (echoing) is a basic debugging technique.